# solve system of linear equations in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab. Suppose I want to solve a linear system of 2 equations with 5 variables x1, x2, x3, x4, x5. Can Matlab give me solution for x1 and x2 in terms of the x3, x4, and x5? I also want to assign values to one or more variables, say I want to look at what happens if x3=5 or x3=3 and x5=1. Is there a way to achieve this?

I looked at the help page https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations.html#d120e14359, but it does not cover the non-square matrix case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple calls of `solve` to get solutions for x1 and x2. In this problem you can solve the first equation for `x1`, and then plug that into the second equation to get x2 in terms of `x3`, `x4`, and `x5`. You can then substitute the new value of `x2` back into your solution of `x1`.

The `subs` function is used to substitute the solved values back into the original equation.

```
syms x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
eq1 = x1 + 4*x2 - 5*x3 + 2*x4 + x5; 
eq2 = 3*x1 + 8*x2 - 3*x3 + x4 - x5;

x1s = solve(eq1, x1);   % Solve x1 in term of x2-x5
x2s = solve(subs(eq2, x1, x1s), x2); % Solve x2 in terms of x3-x5
x1s = solve(subs(eq1, x2, x2s), x1); % Resolve x1 in terms of x3-x5
```

Output:

```
x1s =

3*x4 - 7*x3 + 3*x5


x2s =

3*x3 - (5*x4)/4 - x5
```

You can plug in values for `x3`, `x4`, and `x5` using `subs`. For example, for `x4=3` and `x5=4`:

```
subs(x1s, [x4 x5], [3 4])

ans =

21 - 7*x3
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes the free variables are not clear. Can Matlab figure out the free variables itself? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532039/find-complete-and-symbolic-solutions-to-system-of-linear-equations-by-matlab for a follow up question.