# Find complete and symbolic solutions to system of linear equations by Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have 2 linear equations and 3 variables. The solution is at least one-dimensional. I want Matlab to find all solutions by writing two of the variables x1, x2, x3 in terms of the other one free variable. Is this possible? It seems that Matlab always gives me one numerical solution.

In Mathematica, the "solve" function always returns a symbolic solution, which contains all solutions. But I found Matlab just gives me one numerical solution, which is not very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you define symbolic variables that you're gonna be using:

```
syms x y z;
```

Then define each of the equations. If you have linear system given in matrix form, create equation with for loop.

```
eqns = [x + y + z == 1, x + 2*y + 3*z == 2];
```

Define variables:

```
vars = [x, y, z];
```

Finally, solve it with `solve` with setting `ReturnConditions` to `true`. That way solver with return all possible solutions.

```
[solx, soly, solz, param, conds] = solve(eqns, vars, 'ReturnConditions', true);
```

Which gives following solutions for the example above:

```
solx =

z1

soly =

1 - 2*z1

solz =

z1

param =

z1
```